# JPA update parent child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 object person and address. person is parent and address is child.

- Person : personPK , status
- Address : addressPK , person_fk, status

My repository is extending JPARepository.
`personRepository.save(person);`
is working fine for insert.
But when I update the person object by updating status(eg: Active) in both the tables and use `personRepository.save(person);` My foreign key references(person_fk) is set as null.

My parent class :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="person_pk", nullable=false)
    private Long personPK;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

And my child class :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "address_pk")
    private Long addressPK;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_fk", referencedColumnName = "person_pk", nullable=false)
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

And from my service layer I am updating it using :
`personRepostiry.save(person);`

Any help what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the code where the failure occurs (your update logic)

Comment: @shadab I guess in your `Address` entity you need a member: `private Person person;` instead of a `private Address address;`?

Comment: @sanastasiadis i believe he did not share the full code as if this is the full code it would fail in the add too right?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Yes, insert doesn't seem to work also like this. Maybe there is a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly Change:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_fk", referencedColumnName = "person_pk", nullable=false)
private Address address;
```

to:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_fk", referencedColumnName = "person_pk", nullable = false)
private Person person;
```

then change:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

and add this to your Person class:

```
public void addAddress(Address address) {
    address.setPerson(this);
    addresses.add(address);
}
```

then use:

```
person.addAddress(address);
persist(person)
```

or

```
merge(person);
```

Comment: I had to remove the referencedColumnName from the @JoinColumn annotation to get this to deploy, but once I did, it worked great.  With it in there, I got this exception: MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: person_pk in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(person) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Comment: I down-voted as there is ZERO explanation on why he should do any of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

To update, you first need to fetch the parent entity by id and then update:

```
User user = repo.findById(userId); 
// once the entity is fetched and if it has FetchType.EAGER for Address 
// child, you can do following:
user.getAddress().clear();
user.getAddress().addAll(addressList);
repo.save(user); // -> this will save user and address both
```